# Summing up two Matrices using C functions gives me a logical error

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take the two matrices as input from the keyboard and then trying to print out their sum on screen using C functions. I have been mind-numbing with this code for many hours and still not getting where am I going wrong. It is printing the two matrices all perfect but it's not summing up them perfectly. Although it sums up the first row perfectly but doesn't sum correctly for the rest.

[Output is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwiXV.jpg). In the screenshot, the real output is shown plus the desired output which i want is photoshopped with red.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i,j,order,a[5][5],b[5][5],sum[5][5];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the order of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&order);
    inputmatrixA(&a[0][0],order);
    printmatrixA(&a[0][0],order);
    inputmatrixB(&b[0][0],order);
    printmatrixB(&b[0][0],order);
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            sum[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of A & B\n");
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",sum[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}


inputmatrixA(int *p,int order)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",p);
            p++;
        }
    }
}


printmatrixA(int *p,int order)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix A\n");
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",*p);
            p++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


inputmatrixB(int *q,int order)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter b[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",q);
            q++;
        }
    }
}


printmatrixB(int *q,int order)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix B\n");
    for (i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",*q);
            q++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making incorrect assumptions about the decay of the 2D arrays to pointer types - hopefully someone will answer in detail. If not, google "decay of 2D array to pointer".

Comment: Please show sample input, the resulting output, the desired output and explain what is wrong about them.

Comment: Did you notice that your edit has undone two helpful (sorry for saying so about mine) edits by other readers? Please be more careful with your edits. Please also conisder providing textual data as text here directly instead of linking to a picture of text...

Comment: regarding: `printf("Enter the order of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&order);`  there is nothing stopping the user from entering some larger value, like 10.  there is nothing checking the users input to assure it is in the bounds of 1...5

Comment: strongly suggest using VLAs (variable length arrays) feature,  I.E. do not declare the sizes of the arrays until after the user has entered the 'order'

Answer (score 1):

To explain let's see what happened.

Here when you said order is `2x2` and then entered `1 2 3 4`

```
1 2 3 4 x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
```

And when you are doing the addition you expected them to stay in this order which it isn't

```
1 2 x x x
3 4 x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
x x x x x
```

This is how it is stored in the 2d array. So rest of the positions contain garbage value and you add them. And prints those garbage values.

The correct way to do it would be (You would have to make these changes for other functions also).

```
void inputmatrixA(int (*p)[5],int order)
{
    for (int i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<order;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:-

```
  inputmatrixA( a , order);
```

Note one thing - 2d array which is array of arrays decays into pointer to first element when it is passed to the function. Being said that - that is why we can make changes to the passed array and retain those changes.

This also explains why those second number inside the bracket is needed. Because that will let the compiler calculate the correct position you want to access when you say `a[2][2]`.

You made use of the fact that array elements stay in memory contagiously but you didn't correlate it with the fact that `a[2][2]` is not the 6th element as you thought it to be if the original array is of size `5x5` because `a[2][2]` is really the `2*5+2`th element (if you consider the contagious layout).

Also you have to declare those functions (and also provide the definition somewhere) before you use them or else you can put their definition before you use them.

Comment: @Michi.: It's not about that - declare vs def I know - I was being lazy and putting that you have to put the definition before you use which is one way but not the only way.

Comment: @Michi.: Also declaration if we don't put then also we can write the code - I hope you are aware of that part too. That generated my earlier. And I generalized it - that before you use youhave to define. Definiton is must have.

Comment: I was not thinking in that picture, but you are right:))

Comment: @Michi.: Ok.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In these lines you fill the first 4 elements (for order 2) with values:

```
scanf("%d",p);
p++;
```

The first 4 elements are int line 0 of your 2D array.

In this line you print elements 0 and 1 in line 0 and elements 0 and 1 in line 1.

```
printf("%d\t",sum[i][j]);
```

Choose one of the two ways to access your array.
I think you fare better with using the two-index way everywhere.

Comment: oops. I misunderstood your answer. sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

You have an input that permits selecting the size of your matrix, but your matrices laid out in your software are fixed in size.

Thus, if you input a 2x2 matrix through the UI, it gets stored in a hard-coded 5x5 matrix, and you will not get the input you desire.

I suggest you rework your matrix code to assume a different data structure.  One that looks like

```
int rows;
int columns;
int* cells;
```

where the cells are initialized like so

```
cells = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*columns);
```

Then to look up cell [4][3], use a transformation function

```
int linear_index(int column, int row, int columns, int rows);
```

such that it returns the desired index in a 1-d matrix

```
int linear_index(int column, int row, int columns, int rows) {
    return column + row*columns;
}
```

Note that the above function is just a start, there's no overflow checking on it.  You would be wise to come up with some sort of boundary checking code.

How it might be used would then be

```
int cell_value = cells[linear_index(3, 4)];
```

Finally, don't forget to free the items you `malloc` allocated.

```
free cells;
```